# Magento Varnish Turpentine for CloudFront CDN

Tags: magento, amazon-cloudfront, varnish

I'm running Magento with Varnish and Turpentine and I'd like to setup an AWS CloudFront Distribution as proxy for dynamic contents to speedup the website from multiple locations (static content are already cached).

To make CloudFront cache the content I need to set the Cache-Control header which, by default, is removed by Varnish Turpentine VCL.

I've updated Turpentine Varnish VCL as follows

```
set beresp.ttl = 21600s;
set beresp.http.Cache-Control = "max-age=21600";
```

So the block will be cached on CloudFront for the same amount of time it stays in Varnish cache.

Do you see any issue in this setup?
Can you suggest how to configure Turpentine Varnish and CloudFront to maximise caching benefits?

Thanks.
G

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Comment: I think that *might* be a good idea, but this is one of those questions that may not be a perfect fit anywhere, since it crosses jurisdictions -- it requires an understanding of Magento Turpentine, and Varnish, *and* depends heavily on the behavior of CloudFront, which has a larger base of answers here at SO, and at [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com) and [Super User](http://superuser.com).  But the question should only be posted to *one* SE site.  The question is... which one is right?

Comment: @GirolamoPiccinni the problem is that, with CloudFront, when a requested page's path matches a cache behavior that is configured to forward cookies to the origin, any cached response will only be served in the future to a user presenting the same cookie.  It caches multiple versions of the response, one for each unique cookie value.  Varnish does the same, and changing that behavior in Varnish appears to be Turpentine's purpose... but you can't persuade CloudFront to modify its behavior if the origin server needs to see the cookie.